# Flutter how to use Future return value as if variable

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-future

I want to get `Future` return value and use it like variable.
I have this `Future` function

```
  Future<User> _fetchUserInfo(String id) async {
    User fetchedUser;
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('user')
        .document(id)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) {
      final User user = User(snapshot);
      fetchedUser = user;
    });
    return fetchedUser;
  }
```

And I want get value like so

```
final user = _fetchUserInfo(id);
```

However when I tried to use like this

```
new Text(user.userName);
```

Dart doesn't recognize as `User` class. It says `dynamic`.
How Can I get return value and use it?
Am I doing wrong way first of all?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You forgot use `await` belong to `async` method. That's simple thing.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can simplify the code:

```
Future<User> _fetchUserInfo(String id) async {
    User fetchedUser;
    var snapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('user')
        .document(id)
        .get();
    return User(snapshot);
  }
```

you also need `async`/`await` to get the value

```
void foo() async {
  final user = await _fetchUserInfo(id);
}
```

Comment: thank you. so I need to create function in-place just to receive future's return value? this works but weird!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. I added the function to demonstrate where to place `async`. Your code most likely is already inside a function anyway. You can also always use `.then(...)` with a `Future`. You should also be aware that a `Future` is a unified handler for all kinds of callbacks, so "just to receive future's return value" sounds like you are not fully considering what's actually going on.

Comment: you are right, I am new to Flutter, what I'm trying to understand is why this alone is not possible:
`final user = await _fetchUserInfo(id);` so why to create a foo(); ?

Comment: As mentioned `Future` is about callbacks where your code (the function you pass to `aFuture.then(...)`) is called when the result of the async execution becomes available eventually. If you use `async` this is a sign for Dart that this code makes use of the simplified async syntax that uses for example `await` at that it needs to rewrite this code to the `.then(...)` syntax before the code can actually be compiled. You don't want this automatically because `async` *always* requires the return type of such functions to be a `Future<...>` which one would try to avoid if possible.

Comment: To fully understand `async`/`await` it might be a good idea to create an example that utilizes an async callback, first without using any special Dart syntax support (without using `Future` at all), then rewrite it to use `Future.then(...)`, and then rewrite it to use `async`/`await`.

Comment: thank you so much, will check that, and according to what you just said, that I need to add the stream builder inside a `futer.then(...)` or inside a `async/await` in order to use the `user id` in the `where clause` in this code
`StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>( stream: db.collection(...).where( "userId", isEqualTo: getTheUserFutureOrSomething )`

Comment: mr. Günter, can you please have a look on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56759571/how-to-build-a-stream-based-on-a-future-result-in-flutter
thanks

Comment: helped me with my solution.

Answer (score 12):

### use like this

```
var username;
dbHelper.getUsers().then((user) {
  username = user.getName;
});
```

---

this function returns future value

```
dbHelper.getUsers()
```

it is written like this

```
getUsers() async { .... }
```

Answer (score 4):

To add a little more detail on the original question from Daibaku which might help clarify using Futures in Flutter/dart, `user` was:

```
final user = _fetchUserInfo(id);
```

Without letting compiler infer type, that would be:

```
final Future<User> user = _fetchUserInfo(id);
```

#### Get & Use a Future Value

Daibaku asked how to get the return value of `user` & use it.

To use `user` in a Widget, your widget must watch/observe for changes, and rebuild itself when it does.

You can do this manually with a lot of boilerplate code, or you could use `FutureBuilder`, which has done this for you:

```
  FutureBuilder(future: user, builder: (context, snapshot) 
  {
    if (snapshot.hasData) return Text(snapshot.data.userName);
    return Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0,);
  }
```

More explicitly, you could write the above as:

```
  FutureBuilder<User>(future: user, builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<User> userSnapshot)
  {
    if (userSnapshot.hasData) return Text(userSnapshot.data.userName);
    return Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0,);
  }
```

`FutureBuilder` in the above example, synchronously (i.e. immediately) returns a zero width/height Container Widget, but also attaches an observer to your future `user`, to know when Future data arrives.

When `user` is eventually updated with "data", `FutureBuilder`'s observer is notified and it calls `setState()`, which starts a rebuild of itself.  Now that `snapshot.hasData` is `true`, `Text(snapshot.data.userName)` is returned instead of the empty Container.

---

If you weren't using `user` within the synchronous world of Widget Element tree building and just wanted to print out the value for debugging you could attach an observer using `then`:

```
user.then((u) => print(u.userName));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of getting a value from a `Future`.

1. Using `async-await`:

   ```dart
   int _value = 0; // Instance variable.

   void func() async {
     int value = await _yourFuture(); // Await on your future.
     setState(() {
       _value = value;
     });
   }
   ```
2. Using `then`:

   ```dart
   int _value = 0; // Instance variable.

   void func() {
     _getPref().then((value) {
       setState(() {
         _value = value; // Future is completed with a value.
       });
     });
   }
   ```

Answer (score -22):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

class ThreadExample implements Callable<String>{

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Ashish";
    }

}
public class FutureThreadExample {

    public static void main(String a[]) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ExecutorService executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        List <Future<String>>objList=new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
       for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            Future<String> obj=executorService.submit(new ThreadExample());
            objList.add(obj);
       }
        for( Future<String> fut:objList) {
            System.out.println(fut.get());
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }


}
```

Comment: Read the OP question properly before answering. The post is regarding flutter (dart) not Java

Comment: This question was asked from flutter(dart language). It's not java based question.